# Sorting names containing numbers

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort my tab-delimited data file containing 15 columns according to column[0], i.e. my input file (I illustrate only column 0)

Input file and desired Output file

```
contig1               contig1
contig102             contig1
contig405             contig2
contig1               contig17
contig2               contig102
contig1005            contig405
contig17              contig1005
```

The script below sorts, but since 1 < 2, it gives me all contigs having 1 then passes to 2, also since 0 < 1, is gives me 102 before 2, how to improve it?

```
f1 = open('file.txt','r')
a=sorted(f1.readlines(), key=lambda l: l.split()[0]))
r=open('file.txt','w')
r.writelines(a)
f1.close
```

Comment: Assuming they all start with contig, you could just sort by int(s[6:])

Comment: if that's a possibility, ideally you should have unsignificant `0` digits before the number. Another possibility, if you always have string + number order, would be to split , order by string, then by number, but that's a bit more tricky... And if the string is always the same, Antimony's suggestion is definitely the good one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: it could be a duplicate, but I am specificallyasking how to improve the script I wrote above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
l.split()[0]
```

gives

```
contig1
contig102
```

You want to sort on

```
int(l.split()[0][6:])
```

which is

```
1
102
```

Do

```
a = sorted(f1, key=lambda l: int(l.split()[0][6:]))
```

Comment: There is no need to call `readlines()`, just pass in the file: `sorted(f1, key=...)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Right, I've changed that.

Comment: @dorvak Yes. But does it change? Not in the question. Let's assume the question makes sense as it is asked :)

Comment: Jepp, that's right! (Your solution might be faster than mine (did'nt test this), but it's less generic)

Answer (score 2):

How about this one:

```
import re

def alphanumsort(x):
    reg = re.compile('(\d+)')
    splitted = reg.split(x)
    return [int(y) if y.isdigit() else y for y in splitted]

print sorted(["contig1","contig20","bart30","bart03"], key = alphanumsort)
```